# Copying an XSLFTableRow to XSLFTable using Apache POI

Tags: java, java-8, apache-poi, xwpf, xslf

I have successfully added/copied rows to XWPFTable using Apache POI but unable to achieve the same in XSLFTable. Following is the code for XWPFTable

```
    public void addNewTemplateRowToTable(XWPFTableRow rowTemplate, XWPFTable table, int templateRowId, FormLetter formletter, int rowsCount, XWPFDocument document) {
        try {
            AtomicInteger rowCount = new AtomicInteger();
            //calculating the position to add a new row to the table.
            int newRowPosition = templateRowId+1;
            while(rowCount.get()<rowsCount) {
                XWPFTableRow oldRow = rowTemplate;
                CTRow ctrow = CTRow.Factory.parse(oldRow.getCtRow().newInputStream());
                XWPFTableRow newRow = new XWPFTableRow(ctrow, table);
                List<XWPFTableCell> cells = new ArrayList<XWPFTableCell>();
                newRow.getTableCells().forEach(cell-> {
                    cells.add(cell);
                });
                for(XWPFTableCell cell : cells) {
                    if(cell.getText().contains(HASH_DELIMITER)) {
                        String cellText = cell.getText().trim();
                        //split the text with # sign to get the key.
                        String fieldName = getFieldNameFromPlaceHolder(cellText);
                        String[] textArray = fieldName.split(HASH_DELIMITER);
                        String key = textArray[0];
                        FormLetterTableField tableField = (FormLetterTableField) formletter.getFormLetterFields().get(key);
                        List<FormLetterData> tableRowData = tableField.getTableRowData();
                        Map<String, Object> formletterFieldsRow = tableRowData.get(rowCount.get()).getFormLetterFields();
                        replaceXWPFTableCellValues(cell, formletterFieldsRow, document);
                    } else if(cell.getText().startsWith(PLACEHOLDER_FIELD_PREFIX)&&cell.getText().endsWith(PLACEHOLDER_FIELD_SUFFIX)) {
                        Map<String, Object> fields = formletter.getFormLetterFields();
                        replaceXWPFTableCellValues(cell, fields, document);
                    }
                }
                //adding new row to the table at newRowPosition.
                table.addRow(newRow, newRowPosition);
                newRowPosition+=1;
                rowCount.getAndIncrement();
            }
            table.removeRow(templateRowId);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return;
        }
    }
```

But I want to achieve the same for XSLFTable because I am currently working with .pptx files. The issue is there is no row.getCTRow() function in XSLFTableRow and also I cannot create a new XSLFTableRow like I did in `XWPFTableRow newRow = new XWPFTableRow(ctrow, table);`
because the XSLFTableRow constructor is invisible by default and is not public. Can anyone please guide me how can I achieve the same functionality with XSLFTable for copying XSLFTableRow as I did in XWPFTable as shown in the code above?

Comment: "Can anyone please guide me how can I achieve the same functionality with XSLFTable for copying XSLFTableRow as I did in XWPFTable as shown in the code above?"; No, because  the code above is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Nobody knows what `FormLetter`, `FormLetterTableField`, `FormLetterData` is.

Comment: "... issue is there is no row.getCTRow() function in XSLFTableRow": See [org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTTableRow getXmlObject](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTableRow.html#getXmlObject--).

Comment: "... also I cannot create a new XSLFTableRow ...": Well the Apache POI  programmers might have had reasons for that. But [the source code is open](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_4/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTableRow.java?view=markup) and there is the possibility to invoke a constructor using reflection in Java. See [Class.getDeclaredConstructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-).